# Optimise complex SQL expression

Tags: mysql

This one is simply beyond my ability at SQL.  I have a query that selects all objects with a certain radius of an object which works perfectly. It first creates a bounding box to get all potential candidates and then calculates the radius from within that bounding box to select results.

```
     SELECT *
     FROM (
     SELECT b.*, pr.postcode, pr.prize, pr.title, pr.collection, pr.redeemed, pr.delivery, pr.archived, bt.category, b.id as objectid, b.updated as changed,
            p.radius,
            p.distance_unit
                     * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                     * COS(RADIANS(b.lat))
                     * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - b.lng))
                     + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                     * SIN(RADIANS(b.lat)))) 
            AS distance
      FROM bubbles AS b, bubble_prizes AS pr, bubble_types AS bt
      JOIN (   
            SELECT  ?  AS latpoint, ? AS longpoint,
                    ? AS radius,      ? AS distance_unit
        ) AS p
      WHERE pr.bubble = b.id
        AND b.deleted = 0
        AND b.type IN ($placeholders)
        AND b.type = bt.type
        AND b.updated > $since
        AND b.lat
         BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
             AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
        AND b.lng
         BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
             AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))

     ) AS d
     WHERE distance <= radius
     ORDER BY distance";
```

(This query was derived from this article http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html)

My problem is that now I would like to modify this so that it selects all objects where

b.created = userid OR b.catch_held = userid OR [the objects is within a certain radius of a point (as above)]

It also needs to be efficient.  That is, in the case that b.created = userid OR b.catch_held = userid, I don't want to calculate DISTANCE or do any of the bounding box calculations and I'm not sure how to restructure the query to achieve this.

Note the none distance related conditions would need to remain in place regardless of create or catct_held.  That is

```
        pr.bubble = b.id
        AND b.deleted = 0
        AND b.type IN ($placeholders)
        AND b.type = bt.type
        AND b.updated > $since
```

Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should rewrite you query using only explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

You are looking for efficiency, so there are basically two approaches.  One is to keep the query as it is and use `union` to bring in the other rows.  The other is to modify the query.  For that, just add the conditions in the inner query and in the outer query.  These are simple conditions so it is not so hard.

I'm a little vague on what you mean by "distance"-related conditions.  The following assumes that all the non-join conditions are distance-related:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT b.*, pr.postcode, pr.prize, pr.title, pr.collection, pr.redeemed, pr.delivery,
             pr.archived, bt.category, b.id as objectid, b.updated as changed,
             p.radius,
             (p.distance_unit
                      * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                      * COS(RADIANS(b.lat))
                      * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - b.lng))
                      + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                      * SIN(RADIANS(b.lat)))) 
             ) AS distance
      FROM bubbles b JOIN
           bubble_prizes pr
           ON pr.bubble = b.id JOIN
           bubble_types bt
           ON  b.type = bt.type CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT  ?  AS latpoint, ? AS longpoint, ? AS radius, ? AS distance_unit
           ) p
      WHERE (b.deleted = 0 AND
             b.type IN ($placeholders) AND
             b.updated > $since AND
             b.lat BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit) AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit) AND
             b.lng BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)))) AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
           ) or
           (b.created = userid OR b.catch_held = userid)
      ) b
WHERE distance <= radius or b.created = userid OR b.catch_held = userid
ORDER BY distance;
```

If it is not exactly what you want, then it should be close enough.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gordon. This suffers the same problem I had with the various things that I tried, which is that b doesn't seem to exist and you get:
Unknown column 'b.creator' in 'where clause'.
If I remove the OR statements past distance <= radius it parses but doesn't work.

Comment: @mark . . . The alias on the outer query is `d` not `b`, so that should be used for the outer reference.

Comment: @Gordon - that's so annoyingly obvious - I was so close but kept referencing b in the outer query Doh! Thanks